# Getting no method error in Customers#index while trying to access attribute of Order model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to access customer's name from Customer table onto my Order's action view index. And vice versa.

I am getting this error:

NoMethodError in Customers#index. 
Undefined method `order' for #Customer:0x24f4...

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders, foreign_key: "customer_id"
end

 class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer
end
```

In my migration:

```
   create_table "customers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "customer_id"
    t.datetime "orderdate"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  add_index "orders", ["customer_id"], name:     "index_orders_on_customer_id", using: :btree

end
```

In customer's index.html.erb

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
      <%= customer.name %>
      <%= customer.order.orderdate %>
<% end %>
```

In orders's index.html.erb

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
   <%= order.orderdate %>
      <%= order.customer.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If customers have many orders, then `customer.order` does not know what order you are referring to.  Should your loop iterate of a customer's orders?  Are you trying to show one order or many?  To clarify, change `<%= customer.order.orderdate %>` to `<%= customer.orders.first.orderdate %>` and see if you still get the error.

Comment: I am still getting an error when chaned to this <%= customer.orders.first.orderdate %>
 it says  'undefined method `orderdate' for nil:NilClass'

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Since it is belong_to, it works only on order's view. But raises an error on  customer's view. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have has many relation with customer and order so

In customer's index.html.erb

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
      <%= customer.name %>
       <!-- this will display customers all order and fetch first and then show that order's orderdate -->
      <%= customer.orders.first.orderdate %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach to setting the relationships between your models in the migration:

```
t.belongs_to :customer, index: true
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association

Comment: Did you re-run the migration?

Comment: Also try removing "foreign_key: "customer_id" in your Customer model, you no longer need it with the "t.belongs_to" in the migration.

Comment: Yes I dropped and re ran migrations. and also took out has_many association and kept it blank. I am still getting the same undefined method error.

Comment: Do not remove "has_many" altogether, just wipe out "foreign_key: "customer_id" part. Make it look like has_many :orders

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Since it is belong_to, it works only on order's view. But raises an error on customer's view. Thanks.

Comment: "has_many" association is not working. I only get undefined method 'orderdate' for customer.orders.first.orderdate and customer.orders.orderdate when I use has_many. So this association works only one way? Or maybe there is something missing.

Comment: Assuming "customer has many orders" and "an order belongs to a customer", you should be able to do both of the following: "Customer.find(1).orders.first.orderdate" and "Order.find(1).customer". I'm using "find" here to select a specific instance of Customer class, in your view you probably have that stored in an instance variable (like @customer). So, if you have defined (at)customer in the controller, in your view you can do @customer.orders.first and work with that. For methods yielded by has_many see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference

Comment: You can also verify your associations work in Rails console (rails c) before actually working with them in your views. Also, make sure everything is correct at migration level.